# Mailto links are not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Mailto links are *not* working at all in Chrome (8.0.552.224).

These links are working in IE 7&8, Safari, and Firefox.

In Chrome, we are clicking on mailto links (we have tested this about 25 times now), and things just go into the ether.

In all other browsers, we click on the mailto links, they open up email clients (gmail, outlook, and others), and we can send the email.

But in Chrome, we click the mailto links and nothing happens...

Comment: You need to give more information.  Some code would help.  A link to this page would be fantastic.  Also, I suspect this is an issue on your particular machine, and not an issue with the page.

Comment: Mailto link works fine on Chrome, also 8.0.552.224. Syntax: "mailto:user@example.com"

Answer (score 1):

mailto: links work on chrome, however it won't open a new window with all of the information ready to type up an email unless the user have the plugin that allows for it. If you want to test that the link is working go to your page and right click, you should have an option to copy the email address. Or you can install the plugin Chromemailer.

Update: I'm not sure when, but Google has implemented an update that now opens a window to gmail when you select a "mailto:" link. (presumably only if you are logged into gmail)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me as well:

```
var url:String="mailto:xxx@yyy.zz?subject=subject?body=message"
navigateToURL(new URLRequest(url),"_blank");
```

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

What on earth is url:String?

Comment: Um...this is ActionScript.